# Random.Range is picking two gameobjects instead of one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I have created code for a question generator but every now and then my random.range is picking two of my gameobjects(out of 20). The code should work but something is causing it to pick two. Is it a bug with unity or the code itself? I have created a list and then when the number is picked it should the delete it from the list preventing any number duplication's(same question asked twice).

```
 public GameObject Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, Question5, Question6, Question7, Question8, Question9, Question10, Question11, Question12, Question13, Question14, Question15, Question16, Question17, Question18, Question19, Question20;
public GameObject VerdictGood, VerdictBad;

public GameObject box_QA;
public courtDialogue _courtDialogue;

List<int> list = new List<int>();
private int i, index, calculate, maxquestions;
public bool neverdone;


public void Start()
{
    box_QA.SetActive(false);

    calculate = 0;

    for (int n = 1; n < 21; n++)
    {
        list.Add(n);

    }
}

void Update()
{
    DeleteQuestions();
}

public void CheckQuestion()
{
    index = Random.Range(0, list.Count - 1);
    i = list[index];
    Debug.Log(i);
    list.RemoveAt(index);
}

public void WhatQuestion()
{
    CheckQuestion();

    if (i == 1)
    {
        Question1.SetActive(true);

        Question2.SetActive(false);
        Question3.SetActive(false);
        Question4.SetActive(false);
        Question5.SetActive(false);
        Question6.SetActive(false);
        Question7.SetActive(false);
        Question8.SetActive(false);
        Question9.SetActive(false);
        Question10.SetActive(false);
        Question11.SetActive(false);
        Question12.SetActive(false);
        Question13.SetActive(false);
        Question14.SetActive(false);
        Question15.SetActive(false);
        Question16.SetActive(false);
        Question17.SetActive(false);
        Question18.SetActive(false);
        Question19.SetActive(false);
        Question20.SetActive(false);
    }
}

  void DeleteQuestions()
{
    if (maxquestions == 10)
    {
        StopCoroutine("CheckQuestion");
        StopCoroutine("WhatQuestion");

        Destroy(Question1);
        Destroy(Question2);
        Destroy(Question3);
        Destroy(Question4);
        Destroy(Question5);
        Destroy(Question6);
        Destroy(Question7);
        Destroy(Question8);
        Destroy(Question9);
        Destroy(Question10);
        Destroy(Question11);
        Destroy(Question12);
        Destroy(Question13);
        Destroy(Question14);
        Destroy(Question15);
        Destroy(Question16);
        Destroy(Question17);
        Destroy(Question18);
        Destroy(Question19);
        Destroy(Question20);

        if (calculate > 7)
        {
            JudgeImage.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(6, 255, 0, 255);
            VerdictGood.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("Not Quilty");
        }

        else
        {
            JudgeImage.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(255, 0, 0, 255);
            VerdictBad.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("Not Quilty");
        }
    }
}
```

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNXn8.png)

```
public GameObject judgeFace;
public GameObject prosecutorFace;
public GameObject clientFace;

public GameObject courtQuestions;

public GameObject healthBar;

public int courtIntroCount;             //This variable keeps track of whose line is next in the court dialogue scene.

public GameObject fullTextBox;
public Text nameText;
public Text mainText;

public float delay = 0.1f;
public string fullText;
private string currentText = "";

public GameManager2 _gameManager2;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{

  //  courtQuestions.SetActive(false);
    fullTextBox.SetActive(false);
    healthBar.SetActive(false);
    Invoke("CourtIntro1", 3);


}

IEnumerator ShowText()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < fullText.Length; i++)
    {
        currentText = fullText.Substring(0, i);
        mainText.GetComponent<Text>().text = currentText;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    }
}


// Update is called once per frame
public void CourtButtons()
{
    if (courtIntroCount == 1)
        CourtIntro2();

    else if (courtIntroCount == 2)
        CourtIntro3();

    else if(courtIntroCount == 3)
        CourtIntro4();

    else if(courtIntroCount == 4)
        CourtIntro5();

    else if (courtIntroCount == 5)
        CourtIntroEND();

    // This needs to have a way of checking which question has been disabled after the answer has been selected
}


//  COURT DIALOGUE _ INTRO SEQUENCE

public void CourtIntro1()
{

    courtIntroCount = 1;
    fullTextBox.SetActive(true);
    judgeFace.SetActive(true);
    nameText.text = "Judge";
    StartCoroutine(ShowText());
    currentText = "Court is now in-session.  All rise.";
}

public void CourtIntro2()
{
    courtIntroCount = 2;
    fullTextBox.SetActive(true);
    nameText.text = "Judge";
    StartCoroutine(ShowText());
    fullText = "Now, you, lawyer.  Do you solemnly and sincerely and truly declare and affirm that the evidence you shall give shall be the truth, the whole truth and nothing but the truth?.";
}

public void CourtIntro3()
{
    courtIntroCount = 3;
    fullTextBox.SetActive(true);
    nameText.text = "Judge";
    StartCoroutine(ShowText());
    fullText = "... Very good.  Now, the prosecution would like to begin by asking the defence a number of questions..";
}

public void CourtIntro4()
{
    courtIntroCount = 4;
    fullTextBox.SetActive(true);
    judgeFace.SetActive(false);
    prosecutorFace.SetActive(true);
    nameText.text = "Prosecutor";
    StartCoroutine(ShowText());
    fullText = "I would, Your Honour.  I hope the defence will be able to answer them accurately and appropriately for you and the jury..";
}

public void CourtIntro5()
{
    courtIntroCount = 5;
    fullTextBox.SetActive(true);
    prosecutorFace.SetActive(false);
    clientFace.SetActive(true);
    nameText.text = "Ellen";
    StartCoroutine(ShowText());
    fullText = "This is it!  You'll need to convince the judge and jury that I'm not guilty.  Best of luck!.";
}

public void CourtIntroEND()
{
    courtIntroCount = 10;
    clientFace.SetActive(false);
    fullTextBox.SetActive(false);
    //courtQuestions.SetActive(true);
    healthBar.SetActive(true);

    _gameManager2.box_QA.SetActive(true);

    _gameManager2.WhatQuestion();


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it picks two`?

Comment: So I have a gameobject that contains 20 more sub-gameobjects these gameobjects are questions containing answers. Every time I press a button to activate a gameobject randomly from all the gameobjects that are disabled it sometimes activates two instead of one

Comment: You have a log statement in your `CheckQuestion` function. Does it indicate the function is being called twice? This is almost certainly the issue. Without knowing how the rest of your code dealing with the button works it's hard to give advice on how to prevent it from being triggered twice.

Comment: I have attached an Image so you can see what happens in the console.

Comment: You can see in the image that 5 and 15 are activated and in console only 15 pops up. I have no idea why

Comment: I dont have a solution, but you should refactor your code. 1. Put all questions inside a list and iterate over the list instead of setting all the objects via hand. 2. CheckQuestions should return i instead of setting it globally. I guess the problem occurs that you dont disable the correct number somehow. You should also post "deleteQuestions" method

Comment: for the average user the answer to the question "Is it a bug with unity or the code itself?" is "the code" in 99.99999% of cases.

Comment: Please submit a MCVE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  I cannot reproduce your issue with the code you have provided.  Where are you calling `WhatQuestion();` what does `DeleteQuestions()` do?

Comment: I have reposted the code sorry for any missing lines

Comment: Also your for loop is adding values in range 1-20, you are removing from the list using indices 0 -list.length-2 `Since Random.Range(int) is exclusive`  it is also possible for you to get an index you list doesnt have, your list range is 0 - 19 (20 items) you are saying to remove index 1 - 20(20 would be out of bounds)  Odds are the bug is in your code.

Comment: You still aren't showing us where you are running your "coroutines" even though they aren't coroutines since they dont have the correct return type to be coroutines and you are never calling start on them.

Comment: This is all the code related to the random question generator, the only thing I did not include is the public GameObject Question1 - Question20; which does not make any difference. Also I start off by setting my Parent to disable in the beginning of the scene and then through another script a call the function WhatQuestion() to enable it ? Do you think that what might be the issue here?

Comment: @BlindGuardian show us where you are calling `WhatQuestion`.  As it isn't in this script therefore it does matter.  If you are doing these in multiple scenes are you making the objects persistent through scenes?  AKA calling `DontDestroyOnLoad` on your objects?

Comment: Added the other script and update the current one as well so you can see how my script talk to each other. Also in the second script that I attached you can see that I talk to my GameManager at the last function.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to have more information about how this is structured, but based on what I see here, it looks like your WhatQuestion() method needs to know what the variable 'i' is. This is usually done by creating methods that accept parameters and return values. For this example, it looks like your CheckQuestion() method should return a value of 'i':

```
public int CheckQuestion()
{
  //do some stuff
  return i;
}
```

Then, your WhatQuestion() method should call CheckQuestion() to get 'i':

```
public void WhatQuestion()
{
  i = CheckQuestion();
  if (i == 1)
  {
     //Do your stuff
  }
}
```

You may also need a way to de-activate all of the other questions so that only one is activated at a time. Something like

```
foreach (var question in QuestionList)
{
  question.SetActive(false);
}
```

Then, to activate the one question:

```
QuestionList[i].SetActive(true);
```

Hope this info helps, it's my best guess with what's presented here.

Comment: I just tried what you have suggested but unfortunately it is the same result